# AngularJS dynamic form field ID with a directive not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

When trying to add a directive to a input with a dynamic id, the link method does not properly bind to the object.  Given the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zkFzY/) or html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker-{{id}}" datepicker></p>    
</div>
```

And js:

```
var module = angular.module('myApp', []);

module.directive('datepicker', function() {
  var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.datepicker();
  }

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: linker
  }
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.id = 7
}
```

What I see on the console debugger is that when link is called it is showing the id literally as "datepicker-{{id}}" and not "datepicker-7".

Is there a way to force this to happen?  A better way to implement this?

**Update**: Should have clarified.  The datepicker shows up when clicked, but clicking on a date does not function.  I get the error: "Uncaught Missing instance data for this datepicker"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe you need `transclude:true` in your directive return object, which tells angular to preprocess the markup for things like `{{ }}` bindings.

You also need to wrap the call to `datepicker()` in a `$timeout` to delay the attempt until the next angular cycle runs, ensuring that the translcuded ID is set in the DOM.

This worked for me in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zkFzY/2/)

```
var module = angular.module('myApp', []);

module.directive('datepicker', function($timeout) {
    var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $timeout( function(){
            element.datepicker();
        });
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: linker,
        transclude: true
    }
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.id = 7
}
```

Comment: The id on the inspect element tab still shows 'datepicker={{id}}'

Comment: Should have clarified.  The datepicker shows up when clicked, but clicking on a date does not.  This still doesn't get that working.  I get the error: "Uncaught Missing instance data for this datepicker"

Comment: @DeepankarBajpeyi interesting, the id shows as datepicker-7 for me are you sure the jsfiddle you're looking at has transclude on it?

Comment: Yes. just double checked. wth

Comment: @craineum sorry, I missed that part of your question. I added a $timeout wrapper around where you call datepicker, which seemed to work.  Will update the answer.  From what I understand, $timeout defers calling the inner function until the next angular cycle. I think without it, datepicker() was being called before angular had transcluded the element ID. Wrapping it in $timeout makes sure a proper ID is set before attempted to datepicker-ize it.

Comment: That was it. With that you also don't need the transclude and could remove that from your answer.  Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: I had the same problem with ui-date directive from angular-ui.. I needed to modify the directive code and add the $timeout to resolve the same issue. Thanks Brian