# angularJS associated with datepicker (not JQuery UI Datepicker but something else)

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datepicker

I'm trying to associate angularJS with datepicker which is coming from this site: http://freqdec.github.io/datePicker/
According to the documentation, this is how it create the datepicker based on Id, it only can be done by Id, not class, not jquery obj.

```
datePickerController.createDatePicker({
formElements:{
    "inp1":"%d/%m/%Y"
}
});
```

I'm creating a directive to do it:

```
            .directive('datepicker', function() {
            return {
                restrict : 'A', // the directive is restricted to an attribute
                require : 'ngModel',
                link : function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) { // the link() function is used to setup the datepicker
                    // http://freqdec.github.io/datePicker/
                    var id = attrs.id;
                    var dateFormat = "%m/%d/%Y";
                    var fe = {}
                    fe[id + ''] = dateFormat;
                    datePickerController.createDatePicker({
                        // Associate the text input to a MM/DD/YYYY date format
                        formElements : fe
                    });
                }
            }
        })
```

When I debug, before calling

```
datePickerController.createDatePicker({
                        // Associate the text input to a MM/DD/YYYY date format
                        formElements : fe
                    });
```

I see

```
$(id)
```

returns empty.

```
[]
```

Then I realize that the html element is not created because i see the

```
element
```

is something like

```
<input class="col-xs-10 noPadding datepicker ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" datepicker="" id="{{'licEffDate'+$index}}" ng-model="license.licEffDate">
```

the id in element has not been evaluated yet.

but I can only having this id ready in order to pass it into the datepicker.

Is there anyway to solve this issue?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do two things
`transclude:true` in directive and second  need to wrap the call to `datepicker()` in a `$timeout` to delay the attempt until the next angular cycle runs, ensuring that the translcuded ID is set in the DOM.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19734081/1632286)

Helping [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zkFzY/2/)