# datepicker not working fine when ng-repeat using

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui

I am using ng-repeat in that one field need to have datepicker.without ng-repeat my date picker is working fine in table format but when ng-repeat added then my datepicker is not working getting "jquery-ui.js:8044 Uncaught Missing instance data for this datepicker".I tried below code

```
 <td><input type="text" class="inputhistint datepickershiva"  id="datepicker2" ></td>
     <tr id="copartnerTr10" name="0"    ng-repeat="Details in DetailsList track by $index">
                        <td><input type="text" class="inputhistint datepickershiva`enter code here`"  id="datepicker2" ></td>
    </tr>

<script>
     jQuery.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
                    closeText: "Cerrar",
                    prevText: "&#x3C;Ant",
                    nextText: "Sig&#x3E;",
                    currentText: "Hoy",
                    monthNames: ["enero", "febrero", "marzo", "abril", "mayo", "junio",
                        "julio", "agosto", "septiembre", "octubre", "noviembre", "diciembre"
                    ],
                    monthNamesShort: ["ene", "feb", "mar", "abr", "may", "jun",
                        "jul", "ago", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dic"
                    ],
                    dayNames: ["domingo", "lunes", "martes", "miércoles", "jueves", "viernes", "sábado"],
                    dayNamesShort: ["dom", "lun", "mar", "mié", "jue", "vie", "sáb"],
                    dayNamesMin: ["D", "L", "M", "X", "J", "V", "S"],
                    weekHeader: "Sm",
                    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                    firstDay: 1,
                    isRTL: false,
                    showMonthAfterYear: false,
                    yearSuffix: ""
                };
                $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);


                $(function() {
                    $(".datepickershiva").datepicker({

                        buttonImage: "calendar.gif",
                    });

                });
</script>
```

and my directive is:

```
 .directive('datepicker', function() {
    return function($scope, element) {
      console.log(element);
      element.datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function(y) {
          var edate = element.siblings('.edate');
          edate.datepicker();
          edate.datepicker('option', 'minDate', element.datepicker( "getDate" ));
        }
      });
    };
     });
```

Comment: how are you applying the datepicker to this input

Comment: with id am applying

Comment: post that code also

Comment: change it to class then

Comment: with the help of class also not working Agam Banga

Comment: @Maxi where is the `.datepickershiva` in your input field in question?

Comment: sorry I forgot now am update my class.but am mention in my project but not effected with the class also

Comment: Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733723/angularjs-dynamic-form-field-id-with-a-directive-not-working/19734081) to the correct answer for those who have run into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because id should be unique you can give a try by dynamically  generating id's i.e instead of datepicker2 put $index, then your id's will become unique and you have to use a for loop add datepicker.

or create a directive

```
.directive('datepicker', function() {
return function($scope, element) {
  console.log(element);
  element.datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    onSelect: function(y) {
      var edate = element.siblings('.edate');
      edate.datepicker();
      edate.datepicker('option', 'minDate', element.datepicker( "getDate" ));
    }
  });
};
 });
```

and implement it in ng repeat

```
<input type="text" class="inputhistint"  datepicker >
```

Comment: Thank you for quick replay vikas.when am using this directive am visible the date picker but there is no selectiing any date and am getting this type of message as "Uncaught Missing instance data for this datepicker"

Comment: may I expect replay from you vikas

Comment: now you have different datepickers with different id's use a class to apply date picker instead of id.