# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'currentDay' of undefined when ng-repeat uses

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I am using ng-repeat in that one field need to have datepicker.without ng-repeat my date picker is working fine but in table format when ng-repeat added then my datepicker is visible but selecting is not possible and getting message as below shown.I tried one way that is in fiddle

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'currentDay' of undefined
    at Datepicker._selectDay (jquery-ui.js:8574)
    at HTMLTableCellElement.selectDay (jquery-ui.js:9165)
    at HTMLTableCellElement.dispatch (jquery-1.9.1.js:3074)
    at HTMLTableCellElement.elemData.handle (jquery-1.9.1.js:2750)
```

Comment: show the code how ur handling

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44025073/datepicker-not-working-fine-when-ng-repeat-using/44025356#44025356

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17781425/datepicker-returning-uncaught-typeerror-undefined-currentday

Comment: anoop iam using ng-repeat as table format tr,with in td input type text box using datepicker is displaying but value not selecting