# Jquery datepicker selected date is not considered in ng-change - AngularJS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, parameters, jquery-ui-datepicker, function-call

Kindly help me to solve this issue.
I am using jquery datepicker with AngularJS. I am trying to get the selected date and pass it with a function as parameter. For this I am using the following code.

**Html:**

```
<input type="text" "ng-model="gettingStartDate" ng-change="newTest(gettingStartDate)" />
```

**Date Picker:**

```
$( "#date1" ).datepicker();
```

**AngularJS:**

```
function getOrg($scope, $http) {

  $scope.newTest = function(start_date){
     alert(start_date); 
  };

}
```

Comment: Anything that happens within the realm of a jQuery function or plugin needs to be applied to the Angular scope.  Check out `$scope.$apply`: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such complex UI components need to be wrapped into a directive to maintain a model data binding. For the jQuery datepicker, you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144142/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-angularjs), or google around "jquery datepicker directive".

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" id="date1" datepicker1 ng-model="gettingStartDate" />
```

```js
var app = angular.module('reports', [])
.directive("datepicker1", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attr, $controller) {
            $element.datepicker({
                changeMonth: false,
                showOtherMonths: true,
                numberOfMonths: 2,
                dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    $scope.gettingStartDate = date;
                    $scope.$apply();
                    $scope.fromDateSend(date); // function call
                },
                onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                    $("#date2").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the entire approach. Using jQueryUI datepicker directive:

```
angular
    .module('App',['ui.date'])
    .directive('customDatepicker',function($compile){
        return {
            replace:true,
            templateUrl:'custom-datepicker.html',
            scope: {
                ngModel: '=',
                dateOptions: '='
            },
            link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, $controller){
                var $button = $element.find('button');
                var $input = $element.find('input');
                $button.on('click',function(){
                    if($input.is(':focus')){
                        $input.trigger('blur');
                    } else {
                        $input.trigger('focus');
                    }
                });
            }    
        };
    })
```

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FVfSL/)