# How to add time picker to angularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I'm developing a angularJS application. 
I want to add time picker module which can be called in HTML tag? How can I do that?

It should be like this

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="timeInput" time-pick="HH:MM:SS" time-default="'08:00:00'">
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

There is a great library with a lot of widgets. Its name is [UI Bootrstap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap).
About your question there is there a timepicker [click here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/timepicker).
It is of course an open source library you can adapt the widget to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>
Depending on browser support:<br>
A date picker can pop-up when you enter the input field.
</p>

<form action="action_page.php">
  Birthday:
  <input type="time" name="bday">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<p><b>Note:</b> type="date" is not supported in Internet Explorer.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap a datepicker graphic component such as jquery ui datepicker into a directive. Here is [a related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22455276/2595513) with an example.