# Angular event not working on jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datepicker

Angular event not working on jquery datepicker, am trying to use `ng-change` event on jquery date picker, its not working when date changes.

**jQuery**

```
$('.datep').datepicker({
     format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
     autoclose: true,
 }).on('changeDate', function (ev) {
    $(this).datepicker('hide');

});
```

**HTML**

```
<input class="form-control datep" ng-change="fetchDateBetn()"  name="edate"  id="edate" type="text" value="">
```

**Angular JS**

```
$scope.fetchDateBetn=function(){
        alert("working");
        }
```

Comment: it may help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22455030/jquery-datepicker-selected-date-is-not-considered-in-ng-change-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the angular bootstrap date picker,

```
 <div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
        <datepicker ng-change="fetchDateBetn()" ng-model="dt" min-date="minDate" show-weeks="true" class="well well-sm"></datepicker>
 </div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/wh8y4not/1/)**

Comment: Is there any external library/resource need to be added? If yes, request you to provide link

Comment: @user3107804 Yes you need to add angular bootstrap, click the demo link and see, its there under external resource