# Datepicker not working after Data-dismiss in AngularJs

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I am using jquery datepicker like this:

```
<div class="col-md-2 rowdatepicker">
    <label>
        RECORDING DATE
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="abs-textboxdpsmall" name="textbox-recordingDate" id="recordingDateDoc" ng-model="abstractorServicesParams.recordingDate" ng-pattern="/^(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})$/" required />
</div>
```

--

```
function DatepickerInit() {
    /* For calender control */
    $('#modal-footer').modal('show');
    $("#recordingDateDoc").datepicker({
        showOn: "both",
        changeYear: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        yearRange: '1700:2056'
    });
}
```

This datepicker is in a AngularJs modal and it isworking fine. There is a button in the modal which closes the pop up.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" >CANCEL</button>
```

For opening pop up , i am using below code

```
$scope.abstractorServices = function () {
        ModalService.showModal({
            templateUrl: "Templates/_AbstractorServices",
            controller: "AbstractorServicesCtrl",
            scope: $scope
        }).then(function (modal) {
            modal.element.modal();
            modal.close.then(function (result) {
                // nothing else here for now 
            });
        });
    };
```

First time when the pop up is opened the `DatepickerInit` functions fire and every thing works fine up to here.After clicking on cancel button , the pop up closed. Again opening the same modal, the datepicker is not working even though the `DatepickerInit` functions fire this time also, when the modal load.

I am not able to track the issue, Please help me to identify the issue that why `DataPicker` inside modal is not working after once `Data-Dismiss` initiated from the button control?

Comment: You should use angular-ui datepicker instead, based on jQuery one but ready for angular workflow (and doesn't use jQuery unless it's present). Normally a directive should be use to set the datepicker. https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker

Comment: Can you please create jsFiddle/plunker of ur code??

Comment: You need to describe better the the issue, what module is used for the modal, where the DatepickerInit() is placed, in or out the controller, when it's executed etc. Without this simple informations is difficult to help

Comment: This row: `scope: $scope` looks bad

Comment: Check this out it can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144142/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-angularjs

Comment: use a angularjs directive instead of native jquery plugins: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-date

Answer (score 2):

For opening pop-ups this might work:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'Templates/_AbstractorServices',
    controller: AbstractorServicesCtrl
});

modalInstance.result.then(function (selected) {
    $scope.selected = selected;
}, function () {
    //$log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
```

Check this [`plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/JTkIvBwl9agQCYxLaN6X?p=preview).