# How get long value in datetimepicker in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web

I use date timpicker to show date time. Then store it to database.
But I must in long fomat. I can get value as  2010-10-29 10:40:23 but how I get long value to store to database.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe somewhat it will help

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144142/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-angularjs][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144142/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

Datepicker directive using AngularJS and Bootstrap

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/803247/Datepicker-directive-using-AngularJS-and-Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

convert this date value to long in your angular controller.

```
var longDate = new Date("2010-10-29 10:40:23").getTime();
```