# Jquery UI TimePicker not working within Angular directive

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, angularjs-directive, timepicker

I am using jquery timepicker from [here](http://timepicker.co/). It works well within a controller but not in a directive. I have included the necessary files- jquery.js, jquery-ui.js and jquery.timepicker.js and angularjs.

The code that works inside controller:

```
<input type="text" class="timepicker">
```

and in controller,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input.timepicker').timepicker({});
});
```

The same wouldn't work in directive. I think this is probably because of $(document) not being available inside directive. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144142/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-angularjs) that I should create a directive for the timepicker and I tried that too. There are no errors on the console

```
angular.module('myApp')
 .directive('jqtimepicker', function () {
   return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
     link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.timepicker({});
       }
     };
  });
```

and in the html file,

```
<input type="text" class="timepicker" ng-model="testtime" jqtimepicker>
```

and included files,

```
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
```

Please help.

Comment: I don't see the problem. I've created a fiddle with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/yzk9t49v/ . Can you try to reproduce your problem there?

Comment: Well, I am using the timepicker directive inside a directive. I have edited your fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/yzk9t49v/1/ but this is also working. However, now in my code when I click on the input field, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of undefined` error. I guess this is related to something in DOM manipulation

Comment: Ok. I tried my code in a different directive this time and its working. The problem in the directive where its not working is that I am also using Jquery datepicker there - jquery.datePicker.js and date.js http://2008.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/. If I comment these 2 files out, and then use the timepicker.js, its working like a charm. What do I do?

Comment: try to extend the fiddle example until it shows the error you are facing in your own code. this weill help us to understand what the problem is.