# jQuery datepicker not working

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I've looked at all the similarly named questions and it just makes me wonder more why this isn't working.

I include:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

I have the following in my script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#dateField" ).datepicker();
});
```

This is the HTML:

```
<form>
<input type="text" size="50" ng-model="thisItem.title" /><br/><br/>
<textarea cols="50" rows="10" ng-model="thisItem.details"></textarea>
<br/><br/>
<input type="text" ng-model="thisItem.due" id="dateField" /><br/><br/>
</form>
```

And nothing shows up when I click on the `dateField` input.

What have I forgotten?

Comment: What errors do you get? Did you also include jQuery and the UI CSS?

Comment: what about the jquery file itself? is it included *before* the jquery ui file?

Comment: No errors. It just doesn't do anything. I included the jquery file and the the UI CSS before the UI. Only error showing up is about a favico not found, which comes and goes, which doesn't make sense since I never asked it to include one. Other than that, no errors.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with a jsFiddle?

Comment: You do have the CSS loaded as well, I presume

Comment: I have the CSS loaded as well.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yd1mwfqk/

Comment: Oops, made an edit: https://jsfiddle.net/yd1mwfqk/1/  Which oddly works in jsfiddle! *sigh*...So this works in the fiddle, just not my code. Now I need to sift through my code and figure out what might be killing it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
<link rel="stylesheet"      href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
 $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
 </script>
</head>
 <body>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is actually what I based mine off of originally. Still doesn't work.

Comment: can you please tell more about your testing environment ? which browser you are using ?  are you are using pure html ?

Comment: This is in Chrome (I can see it work on the jQuery site) and no, there's Angular involved at some points

Comment: Check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144142/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-angularjs

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using the datepicker part literally inside the Angular. I happen to also have Angular going on. I'm loading/using the jquery/datepicker independent of the Angular

Comment: could you try  :    jQuery(function($){ // wait until the DOM is ready
            $('#dateField').datepicker();
        });    also try use single quote not double quotes...