# jQuery datepicker with AngularJS: "TypeError: element.datePicker is not a function"

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to use jQuery datepicker in my AngularJS app, but I get the following error message:

```
jQuery datepicker with AngularJS: "TypeError: element.datePicker is not a function"
```

I'm using the code from this answer:
[jQuery ui datepicker with Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144142/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-angularjs)

Here's a working fiddle from that same answer:
http://jsfiddle.net/kevinj/TAeNF/2/

This is the complete code I'm using:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/lib/jquery/jquery-ui-1.11.4.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="app">

<script>
var datePicker = angular.module('app', []);

datePicker.directive('jqdatepicker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
         link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            element.datePicker({
                dateFormat: 'DD, d  MM, yy',
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    scope.date = date;
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
</script>

<p><input type="text" ng-model="date" jqdatepicker></p>
<p>{{ date }}</p>

</body>
</html>
```

What on earth am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

When you load AngularJS before `jQuery`, that will by default use `jQLite` which is smaller `jQuery` API which is been there inside Angular itself.

Basically you need to include jQuery before angular js to use `jQuery` api by default while querying DOM.

Otherwise you need to explicitly use `$(element)`

> **NOTE**
>
> Make sure both the jQuery library version should be same, jQuery &
>   jQuery.ui both.

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TAeNF/1092/)

Comment: Thank you for your response Pankaj, but unfortunately it's still the same. Just in case, I changed to online libraries, but no change. These are the libraries I'm using: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js
http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js
http://codeorigin.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js

Comment: @MarcusEdensky check updated answer.Also make sure library versions should be same.. and use latest angular stable version which is `1.4.8`

Comment: Thank you once again Pankaj, but it still doesn't work. I upgraded to Angular 1.4.9 (apparently stable) and using 1.12.0 of both jQuery and jQuery UI. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @MarcusEdensky could you provide me a fiddle or plunkr? so that I can help further

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the JS files in the following order, mentioned below.

1. > jquery.js
2. > jquery-ui.js
3. > moment.js
4. > bootstrap-datetimepicker.js
5. > app.js (Your angular module reference)
6. > angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker-directive.js

I was facing the same issue, because I missed the `bootstrap-datetimepicker.js` file reference. Hope this helps all :)

Answer (score 0):

Also Check if the jquery-ui is physically present and properly pointed in bower_components.