# Cannot get the input field value using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am unable to find the input field values using Angular.js. I am providing my code below:

```
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
    <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">From Time :</span>
    <input type="text" name="time" id="time" class="form-control oditek-form" placeholder="E.G-9.00AM-10.00AM" ng-model="time" ng-keypress="clearField('time');" maxlength="30">
</div>
<div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
    <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right" style="width:180px">To Time :</span>
    <input type="text" name="time1" id="time1" class="form-control oditek-form" placeholder="E.G-9.00AM-10.00AM" ng-model="time1" ng-keypress="clearField('time1');" maxlength="30">
</div>
```

Here I am integrating the `jquery-timepicker` and the script is given below.

```
$(function() {
    $('#time').timepicker();
    $('#time1').timepicker();
});
```

My problem is, after selecting the time value when I am trying to fetch those value using one `ng-click` event, it's showing undefined.

```
$scope.addTimeDetails = function() {
    console.log('times', $scope.time, $scope.time1);
}
```

Comment: What about the controller?

Comment: `addTimeDetails` is my ng-click function.while i am click on that function after selecting the time in both field .this console message is showing undefined.

Comment: may be this will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144142/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-angularjs

Comment: i think you should use create directive for timepicker, because jQuery manipulates the DOM and angular cannot interpret manipulated DOM

Comment: You might also need to put your `$scope` variables into an object like `$scope.dateFields.time` and `$scope.dateFields.time1`. Also, choose better element ID values than 'time' and 'time1' as they can be easily confused.

Answer (score 4):

Mixing AngularJS with jQuery libraries is bad solution. Problem is next: You are defining ng-model on input and then initializing jQuery timepicker which makes a problem. You should use some third party angularjs library for datepicker or build your own directive. This one is the similar to the jQuery timepicker: [angular-jquery-timepicker](https://github.com/Recras/angular-jquery-timepicker)

Answer (score 1):

This won't work, since jquery-datepicker modifies the DOM.  You can try using [angular-datepicker](https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker) or [angular UI bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Answer (score 1):

ngModels should always have their own object and not be scope properties:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="formModel.time">
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.formModel = {};
```

You will then be able to access the value with:

```
$scope.formModel.time;
```

Comment: I had an input model directly at scope and it was working fine until some point. However, at some point on a single page it stopped working no matter what I tried. On other pages the input is linked directly at scope and they work fine. Anyway, appreciate your comment here, I changed the "broken" model to an object and it started working again. I cannot explain why and how this works behind the scene.

Comment: @user2217057 glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

jquery timepicker may not fire the `keypress` event.

try it with `ng-change`

```
<input type="text" name="time" id="time" class="form-control oditek-form" placeholder="E.G-9.00AM-10.00AM" ng-model="time" ng-change="clearField('time');"  maxlength="30" >
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use third party library in angular, recommended approach is that you create a directive as following:

```
angular.module('app', [ ])
    .directive('timePicker', [function () {
        return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            model: '=ngModel'
        },
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {

            element.timepicker();

            element.on('changeTime', function () {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    $scope.model = element.val();
                });
            });       
        }
    }
}]);
```

and use from as:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="time" time-picker="" />
<input type="text" ng-model="time1" time-picker="" />
```

Recommended resource: [thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: I used your code but its showing the error `angularjs.js:107 TypeError: element.timepicker is not a function` in console.

Comment: do you add this resource in page <script src="jquery.timepicker.js"></script>? try in http://plnkr.co/edit/UHdkgSRX0fv2sUB15FoM?p=preview

Comment: Plz add your code to plunker, and add link in commnt to check

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#time').timepicker({change: function(time) {
        // the input field
        $scope.time = time;
        if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply();
    }});
    $('#time1').timepicker({change: function(time) {
        // the input field
        $scope.time1 = time;
        if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply();
    }});
});
<script>
```

You need to put this code in angular js controller to set values in model instead of putting in HTML.

Comment: Don't mix Angular and jQuery like this EVER.

Comment: i used your code its giving this `angularjs.js:107 SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` error.

Comment: Are you put this code in same controller or just out side? Can you share your controller code?