# Datepicker not working on form populated through angular scope variables

Tags: jquery, angularjs, frontend, jquery-ui-datepicker, angularjs-ng-model

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
          $( function() {
            $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
          } );
</script>

<form>
    <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" ng-model="item[2]">
</form>
```

Consider the code as described above (assuming that the `item[2]` have a valid date value). I want the `datepicker` to popup when clicked on the input field. Unexpectedly this does not work and no date picker popup shows up.

Comment: Firstly, this `$( "#datepicker" )` doesn't match anything. Secondly, you should load it like this e.g: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18447446/1414562  (it should be `$(element).datepicker()`)

Comment: Following your edit, a class is different than an ID... But anyway, you'd have better to provide code you are using, not some random code where it can be more difficutl to catch what is your error

Answer (score 0):

you just need to modify your html for input field:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" class="form-control datepickertouched" ng-model="item[2]">
```

visit this [link](http://jsbin.com/qihufexuva/edit?html,output) for live example.

Answer (score 0):

`$( ".something" )` returns an array of elements. `datepicker()` function needed a specific element. Try this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
      $( function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
      } );
</script>

<form>
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="form-control datepicker" ng-model="item[2]">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
```

Here you are applying datepicker on 'datepicker', where datepicker is id and you haven't assigned id to your input control.
Try below instead :

```
<input id= 'datepicker' type="text" class="form-control datepickertouched" ng-model="item[2]">
```

Answer (score 0):

you should not use jquery in your angular application.
Create a directive something like this

```
App.directive('myAppDatePicker', function() {
    return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
       $(element).datepicker(ConfigOptions);
     }
  };
});
```

And use it like this

```
<form>
   <input type="text" id="datepicker" class="form-control datepicker" ng-model="item[2]" my-app-date-picker>
 </form>
```

Otherwise you can use angular-ui-bootstrap datepicker also in which they have already created a directive and use it

[Here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) is the link

There is another if you want to use angular material design.

[Here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker) is the link for that.

Both are clean and effective.