# ng-model not working with jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, mean-stack

I am creating an application in Mean Stack and I am using jquery plugin for picking the time (TimePicki). When I am typing the text in textbox it is taking it as input but when I am selecting the time by using a plugin ng-model is not working in that textbox and returning undefined. Below is the code.

Express API

```
router.post('/tariff', function(req, res) {
var tariff = new Tariff();
tariff.CabType = req.body.CabType,
    tariff.NormalRate = req.body.NormalRate,
    tariff.PeakRate = req.body.PeakRate,
    tariff.StartPeakHour = req.body.StartPeakHour,
    tariff.EndPeakHour = req.body.EndPeakHour,
    tariff.Status = req.body.Status
tariff.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error in Saving user: ' + err);
        throw err;
    } else {
        console.log('Tariff Saved');
    }
});
```

});

HTML Code

```html
<input id="starttimepicker" class="form-control" ng-model="Tariff.StartPeakHour" placeholder="Starting Peak Hour" />
<input id="endtimepicker" class="form-control" ng-model="Tariff.EndPeakHour" placeholder="Ending Peak Hour" />
```

Controller Code

```js
$('#starttimepicker').timepicki();
$('#endtimepicker').timepicki();
```

Comment: Why are you posting your express API instead of client side code ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to use a directive to pass the value from jquery to angular.

See [jQuery ui datepicker with Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144142/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-angularjs)