# jQuery how to declare a selector function only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a re-useable text input directive in AngularJS:

```
// form.html
<text-input key="first_name"></text-input>

// text-input.js
app.directive("textInput", ($rootScope) => {
  return {
    templateUrl: "/shared/forms/text-input/text-input.html",
    scope: true,
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {

      $scope.key = attrs.key;

      $(document).on('keyup', '.' + $scope.key, function() {
        console.log($(this).val());
      });

    }
  }
});

// shared/forms/text-input/text-input.html
<input type="text" class="{{key}}">
```

When I type something inside the text-input directive it console log the input I set.

However - the problem begins when I move to another page and then return to the same page - then the

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.' + $scope.key, function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Is going to be decalred once again and over and over.
Then - everytime I type something in the text input it not logs once, but 2 times and then 3 times in a row and so for and so on (depends on time the function was declared).

I found a way to solve this out and register this only once by using some if statement like this:

```
if (!$rootScope.alreadyInited[$scope.key]) {
  $rootScope.alreadyInited[$scope.key] = true;
  $(document).on('keyup', '.' + $scope.key, function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
}
```

But that seems not the good way to solve this and this is very annoying.

Maybe can I tell AngularJS / jQuery to clear the registered selectors like the one I have mentioned above on each page changing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing Angular and jQuery is generally a bad idea. They follow different philosophies which more often than not clash and screw up design patterns for both. (as shown by your question)

I would suggest getting rid of `$(...).on('keyup' ...)` and replace it with [ng-keyup](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup)

Example:

template:

```
<text-input ng-keyup="onkeyup()" ng-model="myvalue" key="first_name"></text-input>
```

controller:

```
$scope.onkeyup = function()
{
    console.log($scope.myvalue);
}
```

Comment: But the problem is that I have a template based on jQuery and jQuery plugins, like datepicker and select2 which are using jQuery in order to be fired. I would lovely to use AngularJS by itself but I don't find any good theme for it..

Comment: Then stick with jQuery for now OR look for ng wrappers for your jquery elements: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144142/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

If you use angular, then use angular.

using:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.' + $scope.key, function()
```

is a bad idea what so ever, moreover with angular.

Use [`ngKeyUp`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup):

**template:**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myText" name="myText" key="myRandomName" ng-keyup="onkeyup()" />
```

**Controller**:

```
$scope.onkeyup = function() {
   console.log($scope.myText);
}
```